# How do I set up haskell-mode to generate tags?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I am trying to setup emacs for haskell. I downloaded haskell-mode with el-get and some parts are working (like indentation, starting ghci, etc.) but I can't get the [tags-generation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Project_navigation)  working.

Hasktags is installed, and
`(load "~/.emacs.d/el-get/haskell-mode/haskell-site-file")` is added to my init-file.

Does hasktags need to be in a certain directory? (I added the directory to `PATH`, no success.)

The `haskell-process-generate-tags` function is not available with `M-x`. When I add `(load "~/.emacs.d/el-get/haskell-mode/haskell-process.el")` manually to the init-file the function is available but no TAGS file is generated.

(PS: I am using emacs 24.1 with linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasktags` should be in `PATH`, but are you sure that `PATH` in Emacs is the same as `PATH` in shell? I just tried, and `haskell-process-generate-tags` worked for me without problem. Try to setup `PATH` from Emacs with:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":directory_with_hasktags"))
```

You can also bind `C-x C-s` to `haskell-mode-save-buffer` as described in `examples/init.el` - in this case, you can set `haskell-tags-on-save` variable to `t`, and `hasktags` will be called on every save of you haskell files.

Comment: Thanks! changing the emacs `PATH` solved it.
One more thing: Did you also have to add `(load "~/.emacs.d/el-get/haskell-mode/haskell-process.el")` to your init file? Without it, it still does not work.

Comment: yes, I was need to load it explicitly - this file doesn't have autoloads for this function.

Comment: btw, the loading of `haskell-process` was fixed in fresh versions by adding `provide`...

Comment: What exactly are you adding to the path? I downloaded the package from [hackage.haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasktags) and opened it up only to see some Haskell files. Not sure how to add these to my PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`haskell-process-generate-tags` is obsolete since 2016-03-14.

use `haskell-mode-generate-tags` instead.

How to find this out on your own:

```
M-x describe-function
Describe function: haskell-process-generate-tags
....
```