# haskell-process file not found in haskell-mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I'm trying to follow the haskell wiki to set up emacs to program haskell. I'm using haskell mode, and that seems to be working and okay, but now I try to generate haskell tags to be able to open a file with the M-. shortcut. I installed hasktags and haskell-mode as described here : http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Project_navigation. However, when I try to generate the tags through M-x haskell-process-generate-tags I get a 'not found' error. I found a post on stack overflow about this, [How do I set up haskell-mode to generate tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220672/how-do-i-set-up-haskell-mode-to-generate-tags), which described my problem and solved it by loading haskell-process from .emacs.d/el-get/haskell-mode/haskell-process.el as path.

However, I'm on Ubuntu, and I installed the haskell-mode (and haskell-platform and emacs of course) through aptitude, and that didn't seem to contain this haskell-process.el file mentioned in that post. I then tried to download the haskell-mode through el-get, and that didn't include the haskell-process file either.

So, my question is, am I correct in assuming that I need the haskell-process file to be able to generate the tags, and if so, where can I get that file? I think I saw it in the git repo of haskell-mode, and I can of course pluck it out and put it in my directory, but I've got the feeling that if I have to resort to that, it means I'm doing something wrong.

Kasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs packages are usually outdated in Debian-based distributions, and I think, that Ubuntu still have very old version of haskell-mode. It's better to install haskell-mode via package.el, that is bundled together with Emacs.  Fresh versions of haskell-mode for package.el are available via [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).  The similar advice I can give for other Emacs packages ;-)

Comment: Okay, so I take it that 1. I should have that haskell-process.el file, and 2. that el-get also has outdated packages? I will try to find out how to use the MELPA thingy.

Comment: 2. using `el-get` you always get latest versions, often unstable ;-) 1. haskell-process will be loaded automatically, if you'll use version from github (from MELPA or el-get).

Comment: Alright, I installed emacs24, didn't get the package stuff to work in emacs23 anymore (second try, threw away my emacs config to start over again, a bit impulsive ;-)). Got haskell mode, clearly got haskell-process as well. Now pick up where I left off, and then I'll be back here for another question likely ;-). Thanks!!